# How to navigate to TabbedPage from contentPage backend in .NET Maui?

Tags: c#, .net, tabs, maui

I did created a tabbed page contain an existing page and a contentpage(for test) , in MainPage.xaml i do have a button and I want the event of this button to navigate to the tabbed page .
here is what I tried :

```
  private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new NewPage2());
    }
```

didnt work because Pushasync expecting contentpage parameter , and change it to this :

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       await Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new NewPage2()));
    }
```

it didn't work sayin "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

here is some code of tabbed page and tabbed.cs.
tabbed page :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.NewPage2"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
            android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp1" 
             Title="NewPage2">
     <local:NewPage1 x:Name="tab1" Title="tab 1" />
       
    
    
    <ContentPage BackgroundColor="Red" Title="tab 2" />

</TabbedPage>
```

tabbed.cs :

```
namespace MauiApp1;

public partial class NewPage2 : TabbedPage
{
    public NewPage2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: `it didn't work sayin "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".` What is null? Some relevant code must be missing.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson unfortunately i don't know , i thought the <Local:Newpage1 > is null but I put the tabbed page in app.xaml.cs and test it , it worked totally fine , and you can see tabbed backend there is the initialize methode.

Comment: What is the class (incl. namespace) of Navigation? I see this page; however, MauiNavigationService does not appear to be what you are using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/navigation

Comment: generally a `TabbedPage` is supposed to be the root page, not one that is pushed onto the nav stack

Comment: @Jason you mean tabbedPage it should only be a mainPage ? But basically every app start with authentication interface which is suppose to be the main

Comment: then you would switch from your LoginPage to the TabbedPage by assigning the App.MainPage, not using NavigationPage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason said, you can navigate from the LoginPage to the TabbedPage by setting the App.

In the App.xaml.cs:

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new LoginPage();
        }
    }
```

And in the LoginPage's successful login:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.MainPage = new NewPage2();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually TabbedPage is main page defined, but there is a way you can achive this

```
Shell.Current.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new YourPage(), true);
```

And then from another page to navigate back you can simply

```
Shell.Current.Navigation.PopModalAsync(true);
```